# Is there a way to automatically load environment variables when activating venv?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-venv

I am using python venv to create virtual environments. But, since I am working with several projects with different virtual environments, I don't want to manualy set environment variables every time I switch to a different project.

Is there a way to set venv environment variables automatically when activating the venv?

What is the best practice for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good practice is to use [`dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). You can load your environment by placing your environment variables into a file named `.env`, and whenever you would like to load an environment, just use the lines:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

This has the nicety that it only exists within the scope of you running a single script, since it essentially works like calling `os.environ['variable'] = 'value'` a number of times.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. But I want to stress the subject... is there a way to do this in the venv scope?

Answer (score 1):

Activating a virtual environment is nothing more than sourcing a shell script. You can edit that script to set whatever variables you like. You will probably also want to edit the definition of `deactivate` to clear or roll back whatever changes you made to the environment.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write  a bash scirpt (in case you are using bash shell), where you specified a particular  command which will activate the project python  environment and add the project specific envrionment variable in the system environment. and remove the environment variable when you exit the project python environment.

but i don't this is good/correct way to do things. @mz solution will be correct, where you define a `.env` file and define env variable in it. and use `load_env` to read the env variable when project runs

Answer (score 0):

This concept is based on Two Scoops of Django. I have implemented it using venv.

- Open the Windows PowerShell Script in your virtual environment generated by venv.
- The script is located at venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
- At the bottom of the file, you will see this line of code:
  `$env:VIRTUAL_ENV = $VenvDir`
- Below that code, enter your environment variable as follow:
  `$env:VARIABLE_NAME = 'variable_value'`

Same concept goes if you are using the Command Prompt to activate the environment, you will need to place environment variables in venv/Scripts/activate.bat